# Xquartz won't start, log: Xquartz: start_x11_server: (ipc/mig) server died

Tags: high-sierra, x11, xquartz

I tried to launch Xquartz. It keeps crashing and restarting. Here's the sys log

```
Mar  1 15:24:39 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4868]: xauth:  file /Users/john/.serverauth.4869 does not exist
Mar  1 15:24:39 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[5026]: Xquartz: Unable to locate waiting server: org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
Mar  1 15:24:39 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[5027]: Xquartz: Starting X server: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 --listenonly
Mar  1 15:24:40 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[5026]: Xquartz: start_x11_server: (ipc/mig) server died
Mar  1 15:24:41 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4868]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: giving up
Mar  1 15:24:41 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4868]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
Mar  1 15:24:41 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4868]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: server error
Mar  1 15:24:41 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4868]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server
Mar  1 15:24:41 johns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.macosforge.xquartz.startx): Service only ran for 2 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 8 seconds.
Mar  1 15:24:43 johns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar  1 15:24:43 johns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (WSG985FR47.net.telestream.screenflowhelper[5035]): LaunchServices returned a bundle URL that does not match with the LoginItem's known association.
Mar  1 15:24:43 johns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (WSG985FR47.net.telestream.screenflowhelper): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar  1 15:24:50 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[5036]: expr: syntax error
Mar  1 15:24:50 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar  1 15:24:50 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[5036]: xauth:  file /Users/john/.serverauth.5037 does not exist
Mar  1 15:24:50 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[5194]: Xquartz: Unable to locate waiting server: org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
Mar  1 15:24:50 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[5195]: Xquartz: Starting X server: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 --listenonly
Mar  1 15:24:51 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[5194]: Xquartz: start_x11_server: (ipc/mig) server died
Mar  1 15:24:52 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[5036]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: giving up
Mar  1 15:24:52 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[5036]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
Mar  1 15:24:52 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[5036]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: server error
Mar  1 15:24:52 johns-MacBook-Pro org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[5036]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server
Mar  1 15:24:52 johns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.macosforge.xquartz.startx): Service only ran for 2 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 8 seconds.
```

My mac version is 10.13.5 and xquartz 2.7.11

It used to work a few months ago. Not sure what I did to make it stop working. I did enable drive encryption and get my keyboard replaced, can't think of anything else.